# Go Архитектура приложения

Tags: golang, rest, архитектура, soap

Пытаюсь построить правильную архитектуру для микросервиса REST API 
Стараюсь придерживаться вот этой https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout концепции.

Сейчас архитектура выглядит так:

```
/pkg/logger etc..
/cmd/apiserverr/main.go
/internal/app/
             /rest/api.go
             /store/store.go
             /models/models.go
             /soap/client.go
/config
```

В общем случае модель полученная из request хорошо ложиться в store и пишется в БД.

У меня несколько другой кейc:

1. получаем набор данных полученных из  request (модели для сериализации /десериализации находятся в каталоге models)
2. далее нужно из этих данных собрать другую модель данных (SOAP) и отправить собранную модель в другой сервис http запросом.

Вопрос: где идеологически правильно будет хранить модель для второй "сущности"?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, возможно стоит модель для SOAP хранить в пакете SOAP, т. к. только этот пакет будет ее использовать. Остальные же пакеты, к примеру такие как rest будут ее только формировать. Можете так же почитать про объекты DTO и как их использовать.

Comment: Если я все правильно понимаю (и следуя шаблону DTO) тогда я должен вообще отойти от "общего" пакета model и хранить все модели там где они необходимы.   
Например в пакете rest/models
soap/models
store/models
Я правильно вас понимаю?

Comment: @farex Правильно, но так же могут были и общие модели, если память не изменяет и я ничего не путаю, их называют доменные модели, к примеру модель которая описывает запись таблицы в БД. С этой моделью может работать registry, rest и т.п. К примеру, пакет rest знает, что есть registry и извлекает от туда доменную модель, формирует данные передает их пакету soap, используя уже DTO, в свою очередь пакет soap может так же знать про registry, где сформирует доменную модель и положит в registry. Почитайте про чистую архитектуру, есть книга написанная Робертом Мартином

Comment: Я сейчас в процессе чтения Читой архитектуры, но конкретных примеров применимых именно к Go найти сложно, а сама книга построена больше на теории нежели практики. Те примеры которые есть на github в основном сводятся к полному копированию модели чистой архитектуры, что к Go не совсем применимо.

Comment: Возможно вы видели уже этот пример https://github.com/bxcodec/go-clean-arch
Сделано хорошо

Comment: Спасибо, да видел. Но немного сомнительно т.к не соблюдается тенденция разбивать пакеты по cmd pkg config etc.

Comment: Структура папок cmd pkg config etc т.д. это просто некие рекомендации, шаблоны выявленные в разных проектах. Собственно они в репозитории https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout они так и описали  
> This is a basic layout for Go application projects. It's not an official standard defined by the core Go dev team

Comment: Да я это понимаю, в любом случае спасибо за помощь.